# Why do I have to boot into Windows 10 and restart before Ubuntu will boot?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 15.10, windows-10

This problem started recently, but I'm not sure why.

If I boot my computer and select Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, Ubuntu starts booting and then hangs.

In order to get Ubuntu to fully boot and become usable, I have to boot into Windows 10 and restart. When the PC restarts and I select Ubuntu from GRUB after restarting from Windows, Ubuntu boots fully and becomes usable.

Can anyone help me figure this out, please?

Comment: Did you recently update Windows, install Windows or something? Also, when you're in Ubuntu, run `sudo update-grub`.

Comment: Just done the usual Windows 10 updates - nothing special. I updated GRUB like you suggested. I rebooted and went straight into Ubuntu, so that may have done the trick - thanks! I'd still like to know what's going on, though :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable Fast Startup. If it's enabled, your computer doesn't fully shut down. Instead, it logs you out and then goes into hibernation. Restarts aren't affected by it so Ubuntu boots successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Fast Boot in windows 10. Follow [these](http://www.windows10update.com/2015/05/windows-10-tutorials-66-how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup/) steps. Fast boot doesn't shutdown windows completely but puts it into hibernation and the harddrive partition will refuse to mount if a os is already in hibernation which prevents ubuntu from booting.