# Ubuntu hangs during boot except after booting into Windows first and choosing 'advanced startup'

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows

This has been a really difficult one to Google because I either get results for general boot issues with Ubuntu or for people who just can't access the Grub menu in the first place. My symptoms are really weird.

Ubuntu is installed as a UEFI dual boot alongside Windows 11. However I boot up, I get straight into the Grub menu (so far, so good). If I select Ubuntu after a clean boot, it hangs during the boot process (in various places on different occasions, most often beginning with failing to start Snap Daemon). If I select Windows first, then restart using 'advanced startup', I get the same Grub menu but Ubuntu then boots correctly (and very swiftly, with very little console output, unlike the failed attempts).

The only similar scenario I've been able to find is this one (
[Why do I have to boot into Windows 10 and restart before Ubuntu will boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/751110/why-do-i-have-to-boot-into-windows-10-and-restart-before-ubuntu-will-boot))
which suggests disabling fast boot in Windows. I'd already done this from a different clue but it didn't help.

Also tried without success:

- Updating grub
- Booting with ACPI disabled from Grub
- Disabling secure boot

I can't fathom why booting into Windows first and restarting using 'advanced startup' is impacting the way Ubuntu boots up so far into the boot sequence.

Machine: HP Envy x360 Model 13-ar0001na

Windows version: 11 Home

Ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS

Comment: are you using an HP laptop, by any chance? fwiw, I had a very similar issue where GRUB would hang when booting directly to Ubuntu, but not when booting from Windows "advanced startup". I never managed to fix it, and apparently some HP laptops won't boot Linux at all?

Comment: Thanks for responding. Yeah, it's an HP Envy. That doesn't sound encouraging! When you say that GRUB hangs, at what stage? For me, the failures happen well into the boot sequence after selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu.

Comment: yes, that is different from what I had. grub usually counts down from 10 and then boots, but mine never counted down and didn't respond to input; I had to force-shutdown by holding the power button.

Comment: I'm not sure why that would happen, but it's possible the laptop's UEFI is more tightly coupled to Windows than it should be

Comment: Well the similarity of the link to advanced startup is certainly interesting. Thanks, Esther. Hopefully someone might pop up who knows what the advanced startup could actually be doing.